# Consecutive letter frequency

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write code to determine consecutive frequency of letters within a string.

For example:

```
"aabbcbb" => ["a",2],["b",2],["c", 1], ["b", 2]
```

My code gives me the first letter frequency but doesn't move on to the next.

```
def encrypt(str)
  array = []
  count = 0
   str.each_char do |letter|

    if array.empty?
      array << letter
      count += 1
    elsif array.last == letter
      count += 1
    else
      return [array, count]
      array = []
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error: `undefined local variable or method 'array'`. is there only a missing `array = []` after the def or are there other missing code in your example?

Comment: Splitting hairs, but that's not a *syntax* error.

Comment: sorry, forgot to include the initial array = []

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
p "aabbcbb".chars.chunk{|c| c}.map{|c, a| [c, a.size]} 
# => [["a", 2], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

Comment: Oh, nice. I wasn't aware of `chunk`.

Comment: I don't understand how chunk works exactly. I was on the ruby-doc.org site and was trying to read about it but am still a little perplexed on how it works in this instance. Sorry to be a bug

Comment: In Ruby 2.2, you can use `&:itself`.

Comment: @Kozby [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) works by dividing an array into consecutive chuncks based on the return value of the block. E.g. `"aabbcbb".chars.chunk{|c| c}.to_a` returns `[["a", ["a", "a"]], ["b", ["b", "b"]], ["c", ["c"]], ["b", ["b", "b"]]]`.

If you're still confused, ask another question, explaining what you don't understand about the RubyDoc documentation, and either I or someone else will explain in more detail.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Thanks! I reviewed it some more and do understand how it works. I'm self-teaching so some things are easier to grasp than others. I did figure out what I wanted to do which i posted below, and although it isn't "rubyish" it does work.

Comment: @steenslag  sorry for commenting on an ancient thread... what's happening with the .map{|c,a| |c, a.size]}. I understand what the resulting output will be but there's no reference of map having two objects between the pipes.

Answer (score 8):

```
"aabbcbb".chars.slice_when(&:!=).map{|a| [a.first, a.length]}
# => [["a", 2], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

Comment: The paint is still fresh on `Enumerable#slice_when`.  I see it and `slice_after` were added in v. 2.2.

Answer (score 4):

There's a simple regular expression-based solution involving back-references:

```
"aabbbcbb".scan(/((.)\2*)/).map { |m,c| [c, m.length] }
# => [["a", 2], ["b", 3], ["c", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

But I would prefer the [`chunk` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713412/consecutive-letter-frequency/27713533#27713533) for clarity (and almost certainly efficiency).

---

Actually out of curiosity, I wrote a quick benchmark and `scan` is a little more than four times *faster* than `chunk.map`, but I'd *still* use `chunk.map` for clarity unless you're actually doing this hundreds of thousands of times:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 10000

data = ('a'..'z').map { |c| c * 10 }.join("")

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report do
    N.times { data.chars.chunk{ |c| c }.map { |c, a| [c, a.size] } }
  end

  bm.report do
    N.times { data.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map { |m,c| [c, m.size] } }
  end
end
```

> ```
>      user     system      total        real
>  0.800000   0.010000   0.810000 (  0.803824)
>  0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.192915)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. I saw your answer earlier and wondered about the efficiency comparison. After seeing some amazingly-fast regexes, I suspected your solution might hold its own, but I was surprised by the margin of victory.  I also think your solution reads well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build up an array of results, rather than simply stopping at the first one:

```
def consecutive_frequencies(str)
  str.each_char.reduce([]) do |frequencies_arr, char|
    if frequencies_arr.last && frequencies_arr.last[0] == char
      frequencies_arr.last[1] += 1
    else
      frequencies_arr << [char, 1]
    end

    frequencies_arr
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@steenslag gave the answer I would have given, so I'll try something different.

```
"aabbcbb".each_char.with_object([]) { |c,a| (a.any? && c == a.last.first) ?
  a.last[-1] += 1 : a << [c, 1] }
  #=> [["a", 2], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def encrypt(str)

  count = 0
  array = []
  str.chars do |letter|

    if array.empty?
      array << letter
      count += 1
    elsif array.last == letter
      count += 1
    else
      puts "[#{array}, #{count}]"
      array.clear
      count = 0
      array << letter
      count += 1
    end
  end
  puts "[#{array}, #{count}]"
end
```

Answer (score -2):

There are several errors with your implementation, I would try with a hash (rather than an array) and use something like this:

```
def encrypt(str)

  count = 0
  hash = {}
  str.each_char do |letter|

    if hash.key?(letter)
      hash[letter] += 1
    else
      hash[letter] = 1
    end

  end

  return hash
end

puts encrypt("aabbcbb")
```

Comment: Isn't that just counting chars though? That's not what the OP wants.

Comment: Also very un-Rubyish. Drop the `if/else` and just give your hash a default value: `hash = Hash.new(0)`.

Comment: the problem asked of me was to use an array, not a hash. I did forget to include the new array, which i just edited. I am on a very beginner level, btw

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't realize you wanted counts of consecutive instances. My approach won't work then.