# String compressor (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

Here is my code in ruby for a word compression.
For any given word (e.g. abbbcca) the compressed word/output should be in the format as "letter+repetition" (for above example, output: a1b3c2a1).

Here I'm so close to the completion but my result isn't in the expected format. It's counting the whole letters in `string.chars.each` thus resulting output as `a2b3c2a2`.

Any help?

```
def string_compressor(string)
  new_string = []
  puts string.squeeze

  string.squeeze.chars.each { |s|
    count = 0

    string.chars.each { |w|
      if [s] == [w]
        count += 1
      end
    }

    new_string << "#{s}#{count}"
    puts "#{new_string}"
  }

  if new_string.length > string.length
    return string
  elsif new_string.length < string.length
    return new_string
  else "Equal"
  end
end

string_compressor("abbbcca")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consecutive letter frequency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713412/consecutive-letter-frequency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'abbbcca'.chars.chunk{|c| c}.map{|c, a| [c, a.size]}.flatten.join
```

Adapted from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713412/consecutive-letter-frequency).

Similar:

```
'abbbcca'.chars.chunk{|c| c}.map{|c, a| "#{c}#{a.size}"}.join
```

See [chunk documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)

Comment: `.each_char.chunk(&:itself).flat_map {|l, arr| [l, arr.size]}.join` - shorter way

Comment: 'abbbcca'.split('').chunk{|i| i}.to_a.map{|k, v| [k, v.size]}.join

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for that.

```
'abbbcca'.gsub(/(.)\1*/) { |m| "%s%d" % [m[0], m.size] }
  #=> "a1b3c2a1"
```

The regular expression reads, "match any character, capturing it in group 1. Then match the contents of capture group 1 zero or more times".

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your code counts every letter in the string, not just the one grouped next to one another.

Here's a modified version :

```
def display_count(count)
  if count == 1
    ""
  else
    count.to_s
  end
end

def string_compressor(string)
  new_string = ''
  last_char = nil
  count = 0

  string.chars.each do |char|
    if char == last_char
      count += 1
    else
      new_string << "#{last_char}#{display_count(count)}" if last_char
      last_char = char
      count = 1
    end
  end

  new_string << "#{last_char}#{display_count(count)}" if last_char

  new_string
end

p string_compressor('abbbcca') #=> "ab3c2a"
p string_compressor('aaaabbb') #=> "a4b3"
p string_compressor('aabb')    #=> "a2b2"
p string_compressor('abc')     #=> "abc"
```

Note that with `display_count` removing `1`s from the string, `new_string` can never be longer than `string`. It also probably isn't a good idea to return `Equal` as a supposedly compressed string.

To decompress the string :

```
def string_decompressor(string)
  string.gsub(/([a-z])(\d+)/i){$1*$2.to_i}
end

p string_decompressor("a5b11")  #=> "aaaaabbbbbbbbbbb"
p string_decompressor("ab3c2a") #=> "abbbcca"
```